# Database design for multi tenant users

Tags: c#, database

I am stuck with an issue regarding 2 tables for my users and tenants.

Currently the rules are 1 Tenant can have Many Users

1 User can belong to Many Tenants

This is my User Structure:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public IList<UserPasswordHistory> UserPasswordHistory { get; } = new List<UserPasswordHistory>();
    public IList<UserPasswordPolicy> UserPasswordPolicy { get; } = new List<UserPasswordPolicy>();
    public IList<UserTenant> UserTenant { get; } = new List<UserTenant>();

}
```

I have 2 tables named UserPasswordPolicy and UserPasswordHistory. These tables do not belong to any Tenants.

1 User can have 1 UserPasswordPolicy and 1 UserPasswordHistory

The problem is that if a Manager role within a Tenant wants to change the settings for UserPasswordPolicy and UserPasswordHistory, they aren't just changing it for the User within their own Tenant, they are effectively affecting other Tenants as well.

I thought about moving the table from UserPasswordPolicy and UserPasswordHistory to TenantPasswordPolicy and TenantPasswordHistory but since it affects the User that might be have other Tenants as well.

What can I do to make sure that when a Manager role within a Tenant changes a password policy, it only affects the User within that policy?

Comment: sounds like you want a password per tenant for a given user.

Comment: Yeah.  I was trying not to go that route because that would mean that I have to adjust more tables.

Comment: well, you can't really have password policies per tenant as they may end up conflicting.  If you can guarantee all policies are compatible, then you may not have to.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your reply. I'll have to adjust the database accordingly.